# How to bypass 403 forbidden exception when request use HTTPWEBREQUEST

Tags: c#, winforms, web-applications

How to bypass 403 forbidden exception, when request is:

> HTTPWEBREQUEST

```
try
{
} 
catch 
{ 
   // what do I write in here 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "bypass" it - if the web server is tell you you're not allowed to get the data, you can't get the data. If you don't *need* that response then that's fine - handle the exception and keep going in whatever way you need to.

Alternatively, work out *why* you're getting that response, and perform whatever authentication you need in order to make a successful request. Without knowing anything about what you're trying to fetch, it's hard to suggest anything more concrete.

Comment: i remember i read a question tell that. they use catch to get data. but i cant find that question. plz write help me that code

Comment: @NguyenVietHung: You can get the `WebResponse` from the `WebException`, but that won't include the data that you're not allowed to look at. It will include any more details of the response, but that's all. It would be pretty rubbish security if it said, "You're not allowed to see this page, but here it is anyway."